# @javax.jws.WebService wsdlLocation ("WSLD file not found" - IBM RAD 9.0)

Tags: java, wsdl, websphere, jax-ws, ibm-rad

I've had a web service, designed with WSDL-first with some methods defined withing. A WSDL file is stored in `src\main\resources\wsdl\myservice.wsdl`. The java source is generated with `mvn jaxws:wsimport`.

Today I've added a simple method to the WebService and I've regenerated the sources. The RAD shows no error for the wsdl. However, it do shows not the error "WSDL file not found" on the servlet classes:

```
@javax.jws.WebService(wsdlLocation = "wsdl/myservice.wsdl",  
endpointInterface = "com.example.MyService",  
targetNamespace = "http://example.com/myservice",  
serviceName = "myservice", portName = "myserviceSOAP11")
@javax.xml.ws.BindingType(value = javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding.SOAP11HTTP_BINDING)
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService
```

Nothing has changed in that class, except a new method was defined.

I can't deploy the service now to the WebSphere, because of those validation errors. Where do those errors come from? Can it be an error in WSDL? If so, how can I check which, when IBM RAD 9.0 gives me absolute no error messages about the WSDL itself?

**--edit--**
I was able to move all changes to the project copy loaded in older version of RAD (8.0) and managed to start and test the webservice. It look like RAD 9.0 doesn't accept some otherwise legal construction in WSDL. However, without giving any specific message. Is it possible to find out what line/construction exactly is causing problems for that IDE?

Comment: The same code is working in WAS7

Comment: Please update your question to include the exact details of what is happening now (your comment above has different info from the original question), including stack traces

Answer (score 2):

Here are some settings I have in RAD 9 for which it works. So I'm making some assumptions about your project structure.

- I have wsdl file in `src/main/resources/wsdl` folder. I'm assuming your resources folder contains also `WEB-INF` folder and web pages (actually I'm using `webapp` folder instead of `resources`, but it should work similarly).
- My service implementation is in `src/main/java` folder.
- In `Window > Preferences > Java EE > Maven > Maven Project Settings` I have set Maven values.
- In selected project `Properties > Deployment Assembly` I have `resources` folder set to deploy to `'/'`

Comment: Sorry to mention, mine is ant project

Comment: @SireeshYarlagadda I dont see anything like `Ant project`. You can have either directory structure based on Eclipse/WTP project or Maven project. You can use Ant to build project. Your directory structure is more like Maven than WTP. Is your project correctly recognized as Web Project? If you can add screenshots with Project explorer containing your directory structure, Java Build Path sources, and Deployment Assembly window.